# Show $K＝\{g\in S_4\mid\forall x\in G, (gx)H＝xH\}$ is isomorphic to Klein four group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be symmetric group of order $4$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ generated by two elements $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(2,4)$.
Then, Let

$$K＝\{g\in G\mid \forall x\in G, (gx)H＝xH\}\tag{1}$$

Then, I'd like to prove $G/K$ is isomorphic to symmetric group of order $3$.

I thought $K$ should be isomorphic to Klein four group or $A_4$, because what we want to prove is true, $K$ should be order $4$, and normal subgroup of S4 of order $4$ is just Klein four group.

But I cannot prove $K$ is isomorphic to Klein four.
(I don't know the heart of $(1)$)

Could you tell me the proof of $K$ is isomorphic to Klein four, or, all element of $K$? (Maybe before listing all elements of $K$, we can deduce that $K$ is isomorphic to Klein four.)

Comment: Do you mean $K=\{\,g\in G\mid \forall x\in G,\,(gx)H=xH\,\}$?  And what is $H$?

Comment: Thank you, I modified question.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that $(gx)H=xH$ if and only if $x^{-1}gx=x^{-1}(gx)\in H$.

In other words, $g\in G$ is contained in $K$ if and only if all of its conjugates are in $H$, i.e., the conjugacy class containing $g$ is completely covered by $H$.

As for $H$, observe that $(1~2~3~4)$ is of order $4$ and $(2~4)$ is of order $2$, where $$(1~2~3~4)(2~4)=(1~2)(3~4),\quad(2~4)(1~2~3~4)^{-1}=(2~4)(1~4~3~2)=(1~2)(3~4);$$ that is, $$(1~2~3~4)(2~4)=(2~4)(1~2~3~4)^{-1}.$$ It follows that $H\cong D_8$, the dihedral group of squares. We can then easily write the elements in $H$ by
$$H=\{\operatorname{id},(1~3),(2~4),(1~2)(3~4),(1~3)(2~4),(1~4)(2~3),(1~2~3~4),(1~4~3~2)\}.$$

Consider the conjugacy classes in $S_4$ now:

- the conjugacy class of the identity map, size $1$;
- the conjugacy class of transpositions, size $6$;
- the conjugacy class of $(a~b)(c~d)$, size $3$;
- the conjugacy class of $3$-cycles, size $8$;
- the conjugacy class of $4$-cycles, size $6$.

The conjugacy classes totally covered by $H$ are the class of the identity map, and the class of $(a~b)(c~d)$. Therefore, $$K=\{\operatorname{id},(1~2)(3~4),(1~3)(2~4),(1~4)(2~3)\}.$$ Apparently, $K\cong V_4$, the Klein's four group.

Comment: What do you mean by ' covered by H '? What is the definition of 'covered by H'?

Comment: Sorry for this ambiguous terminology. It just means that a conjugacy class is totally contained in $H$. I have no idea why I wrote this before...

Comment: I understood! Your way is very clear. Thank you. May I ask you  about another answer's approach? I asked why another way works in comment, but there is no reply.

Answer (score 2):

We have $K=\cap_{x\in G} H^x$, where $H^x=xHx^{-1}$. Since $(1234)^2=(13)(24)$ and $(1234)(24)=(12)(34)$, it folows that $K=\langle(12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$. So $K$ is  the Klein four-group.

Comment: Could you tell me why checking (1234)^2＝(13)(24) and (1234)(24)＝(12)(34) implies K is generated by (13)(24) and (12)(34) ?

Comment: 1) This test allows us to say that $V_4=\langle(12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$.

2) Since $V_4$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$, then $V_4<\cap_{x\in G}H^x=K$.

3) Since $K<H$, $K\neq H$, it follows that $|K|\leq4$.

From 2 and 3 it follows that $K=V_4$.

Comment: How do you check $K$ is not $H$?

Comment: From my answer, $g\in K$ if and only if $x^{-1}gx\in H$ for all $x\in G$, which is equivalent to $g\in xHx^{-1}$ for all $x\in X$. This gives $K=\bigcap_{x\in G}{xHx^{-1}}=\bigcap_{x\in G}{H^x}$. In particular, since $eHe^{-1}=H$ where $e$ is the identity, it follows that $K\leq H$.

Comment: @Nekojiru, This can be done in many ways.
One can, for example, do it this way.

Since $(14)(24)(14)=(124)\notin H$.

So if $x=(14)$, then $H^x\neq H$ and $K\leq H\cap H^x<H$. In general, I like your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your kindful comments.